# Find $f$ such that $\frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}f(x)=f\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Which non-constant functions $f$ (if any) satisfy $\dfrac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2}f(x)=f\left(\sqrt{x}\right)$ for $x>0$?

I suspect there is no $f$ which satisfies the differential equation, but I cannot prove this.

Comment: Constants are trivial solutions. I am not sure about any others.

Comment: @Ian the only valid constant solution is $f(x)=0$

Comment: Constants? You mean the zero solution?

Comment: Sorry, no constant functions. I should have noted that.

Comment: @Ian $0 = C$ only for $C=0$ :P

Comment: Never mind, silly mistake, you're right, it has to be 0.

Comment: The first step should be to set $u=\sqrt x$ and rewrite everything in terms of $u$. I suspect there are solutions.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I don't see the solution. Can I get another hint?

Comment: I don't know the solution. But use the chain rule to convert (carefully) $x$ derivatives into $u$ derivatives.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom No, it's not $$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} f(x^2).$$ You get $f''(u^2) = f(u)$.

Comment: You could always try making educated guesses of possible solutions. The ODE is very reminiscent of the basic linear ODE $f''-f=0$, so any non-constant solution is probably gonna be some hyperbolish trigonometresque function like Shi or Sinhc and the like.

Comment: $x^4$ is almost an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I messed up in my first response, but realised this may be a lot easier after all.  Look at analytic solutions here and expand in series.

$$f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} f_j x^j$$

$$f''(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (j+1) (j+2) f_{j+2} x^j$$

Plug in $x^2$ in the latter and equate like coefficients.  This gives:

$$(j+1) (j+2) f_{j+2} = f_{2j}$$

and

$$f_{2j+1} = 0$$

Now, you can just read off the coefficients by starting with $j=0$ and going through the even values.

$$f_0 = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot f_2$$

$$f_4 = 3 \cdot 4 \cdot f_4$$
or
$$f_4 = 0$$

$$f_8 = 5 \cdot 6 \cdot f_6$$

$$f_{12} = 7 \cdot 8 \cdot f_8$$

Can you see how this can be consistently extended?

Comment: What is the radius of convergence of the resulting series?

Comment: For every even $n$, $f_n$ is eventually a multiple of $f_k=0$ for some odd $k$.  (You skipped $f_6=4\cdot 5\cdot f_5=0$, for instance.)  So there can't be any entire solutions.

Answer (score -1):

shouldn't you integrate twice to answer? making the answer (4/15)x^5/2 + c

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E2%2Fdx%5E2+4%2F15x%5E%285%2F2%29

Comment: You need to get $f(\sqrt x)$ as the second derivative, which in this case would be $4/15 \sqrt x ^{5/2}$, not $\sqrt x$

Comment: This is not correct. Differential equations are not amenable to this approach in general.